# selenium dotnet tests from MSBuild in firefox fail

Tags: selenium, msbuild, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests, hottowel

I try to execute a coded UI test (`BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "firefox";`) from MSBuild but the "firefox" never launch and the build failed show the next error:

```
Test method SolutionX.UITests.NewTestUIX.NewtTestMethod threw exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Error Detail:

```
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowserProxy.ProxyFirefoxDriver.<>c__DisplayClass54.<.ctor>b__52()
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowserProxy.FuncInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1 function)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowserProxy.ProxyFirefoxDriver..ctor(ProxyFirefoxProfile profile)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.BrowserServices.FirefoxBrowserService.InitializeWebDriver(String[] args)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.<.cctor>b__1(String[] args)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.Launch(Uri uri)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserFactory.Launch(Uri uri)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.LaunchPrivate(Uri uri)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.<>c__DisplayClass3d.<Launch>b__3c()
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.Launch(Uri uri)
SolutionX.UITests.UIMap.StartApp() in c:\SolutionX\Builds\Agent1\SolutionX\IntegrationSolutionX\Sources\SolutionX.UITests\UIMap.Designer.cs: line 1334
SolutionX.UITests.NewTestUIX.NewtTestMethod() in c:\SolutionX\Builds\Agent1\SolutionX\IntegrationSolutionX\Sources\SolutionX.UITests\NewTestUIX.cs: line 33
```

But later I try with "chrome" and it work fine, the error only appeared with "firefox".

The coded UI tests with "firefox" in my local machine works fine, but from MSBuild did'nt work.

I have a test scenario with a SPA ([Hottowel from John Papa](http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/)) with the next versions:

```
I use Breeze 1.4.5, Durandal 2.0.1, Knockout 3.0.0, Bootstrap 3.0, jquery 2.0.3
```

I have the next versions:

```
Firefox 25
Google Chrome 29.0.1547.76 m
chromedriver_win32_2.3
selenium-dotnet-strongnamed-2.35.0
VS2013
Machine of build: Windows Server 2012
```

Comment: Post a small reproducible scenario of the problem and the *full* error.

Comment: Thanks for response. I was edited the question and I added some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the similar issue in my one of the machine where it worked in another. The reason for it not working on one of my machine was fresh installation of firefox when never opened. After opening firefox once manually, script worked fine.